# MyComboBox with OnTextChanged event in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I want to implement simple MyComboBox with two events overrided - LostFocus and OnTextChanged, but I can't got access to OnTextChanged event (I guess it is because it comes from TextBoxBase). I want to have my own ComboBox, which immediately set (mod 360) value on TextChanged and add 360 on LostFocus.

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    protected override void OnLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int variable;

        if (int.TryParse(Text, out variable))
        {
            if (variable < 0)
                Text = (variable + 360).ToString();
        }
    }
    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) //It is only for preview what I want to do
    {
        int variable;
        if (int.TryParse(Text, out variable))
        {
             variable = variable % 360;
             Text = variable.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Text is what you're handling the textchanged event for. When you get that working you will have an infinite loop. Setting the text of a combobox will make the ontextchanged event fire.

Comment: My question is - How to override OnTextChanged event, or set correct value (mod 360) immediately after text changed.

Comment: Have you tried using `Binding` with a `converter`?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom combobox by deriving from combobox and getting the style of the default combobox.

An article in general for custom controls is available [here](https://www.wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html).

You can get the default style from a WPF element by selecting it in the xaml designer -> Edit Template -> Edit a copy and move the created style into a resource dictionary.

Afterwards you can get the Editor and assign /propagade the function from your custom control eg.:

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
....
private TextBox _partEditor;

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    Unloaded += OnUnloaded;

    _partEditor = GetTemplateChild(@"PART_EditableTextBox") as ItxWpfTextBoxBaseBase;
    if (_partEditor == null)
        return;

    _partEditor.TextChanged += PART_Editor_OnTextChanged;
}

private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    if (_partEditor == null)
        return;

    _partEditor.TextChanged -= PART_Editor_OnTextChanged;
    _partEditor = null;
}
```

Sorry an easier way is not known to me.